# Can this MySQL query "LEFT JOIN ON FIND_IN_SET" be more simplified?

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, count, left-join

I am using two tables:

tbl_category, {"id", "title", "details"}

tbl_items, {"id" "title", "parents"}

Right now i am using the below query, but have to use 'tbl_category' twice. Can it be more simplified?

```
SELECT a.id
     , a.title
     , a.details
     , d.itemscount 
  FROM tbl_category a
  LEFT 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT b.id myid
            , COUNT(c.id) itemscount
         FROM tbl_category b 
         LEFT 
         JOIN tbl_items c 
           ON FIND_IN_SET(b.id,c.parents) 
        GROUP 
           BY b.id
     ) d 
    ON d.myid = a.id
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you might want to read this: [Is adding the ‘tbl’ prefix to table names really a problem?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/154251/)

Comment: See about normalisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT c.id, c.title, c.details, 
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM tbl_items i
        WHERE FIND_IN_SET(c.id, i.parents) 
    ) AS itemscount
FROM tbl_category c
```

Note that storing CSV lists in a relational database is bad design, and should be avoided. Recommended reading: [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3653462/10676716).

Comment: Thanks, a lot. Its exactly what i wanted .Its  a old database records stored as list in a column  i am handlig. So had to deal with it any how. Thanks a lot for instant help